# Enabling a Submit button onclick of another button in a single page app in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-routing

I have an AngularJS app where I am using `UI-Router`. There I want to disable a submit button in the beginning and enable it after a user clicks a particular another button. (Try using `ng-disabled`).

Answer (score 2):

To do so, you can use `ng-disabled` as you say.

On your HTML you will have 2 button. The 1st one which is suppose to disable the other one. This one will have a `ng-click` to change the boolean which is use in the `ng-disabled`.

```
  <button ng-click="disable()">Disable</button>
  <button ng-disabled="isDisabled">Submit</button>
```

And then in your controller :

```
$scope.isDisabled = true;

$scope.disable = function(){
  $scope.isDisabled = !$scope.isDisabled;  
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qgwokh6f/2/)

Answer (score 2):

in controller set initial scope variable,

```
$scope.isDisabled= true;
```

in html file

```
<button ng-disabled="isDisabled">Submit Button</button>
```

and on click of another button set its value to false

```
 $scope.another_btn_click = (function(){      
   $scope.isDisabled= false;
 });
```